# Pandas pivot_table on date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with a date column. It is not an index.

I want to make a pivot_table on the dataframe using counting aggregate per month for each location.

The data look like this:

```
['INDEX']                 DATE LOCATION  COUNT
0          2009-01-02 00:00:00      AAH      1
1          2009-01-03 00:00:00      ABH      1
2          2009-01-03 00:00:00      AAH      1
3          2009-01-03 00:00:00      ABH      1
4          2009-01-04 00:00:00      ACH      1
```

I used:

`pivot_table(cdiff, values='COUNT', rows=['DATE','LOCATION'], aggfunc=np.sum)`

to pivot the values. I need a way to convert cdiff.DATE to a month rather than a date.
I hope to end up with something like:
The data look like this:

```
  
  MONTH LOCATION  COUNT
January      AAH      2
January      ABH      2
January      ACH      1
```

I tried all manner of `strftime` methods on cdiff.DATE with no success. It wants to apply the to strings, not series object.

Comment: I've provided several detailed examples and alternative approaches in this  [**Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/2336654) that you or others might find helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
months = cdiff.DATE.map(lambda x: x.month)
pivot_table(cdiff, values='COUNT', rows=[months, 'LOCATION'],
            aggfunc=np.sum)
```

To get a month name, pass a different function or use the built-in `calendar.month_name`. To get the data in the format you want, you should call `reset_index` on the result, or you could also do:

`cdiff.groupby([months, 'LOCATION'], as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: Thanks @Wes, `cdiff['month'] = cdiff.DATE.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%B'))` did the trick to convert to months.